# How to run this jquery function with input type button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can i perform this jquery validation with input type button ? when i switch to input type submit it's working, but i don wan input type submit because submit button will always reload my screen with modernizr.custom.js UI. Please help, thanks.

```
<script src="js/modernizr.custom.js"></script> 
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
         $(document).ready(function() {
           $('#submit').click(function (e) {
               var isValid = true;
               $('#VEHNO').each(function () {
                if ($.trim($(this).val()) == '') {
                    isValid = false;
                    $(this).css({
                           "border": "1px solid red",
                           "background": "#FFCECE"
                           });
                  }
                 else {
                     $(this).css({
                             "border": "",
                             "background": ""
                                });
                      }
                 });
                 if (isValid == false)
                      e.preventDefault();
                   });
     });
       </script>
```

### html

```
<input type="text" class="input-name" id="VEHNO" name="VEHNO" type="text" />
<input type="button" value="Submit" name="submit"/>
```

Comment: Keep in mind, that a form can be submitted without using the submit button. For example pressing the `Enter` key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to use jQuery Id selector for a button but you have not assigned an id to your button, after you attach an id, it will work fine.

```
    $(document).ready(function () {

         $('#someId').click(function () {

             var isValid = true;

             $('#VEHNO').each(function () {
                 if ($.trim($(this).val()) == '') {
                     isValid = false;
                     $(this).css({
                         "border": "1px solid red",
                             "background": "#FFCECE"
                     });
                 } else {
                     $(this).css({
                         "border": "",
                             "background": ""
                     });
                 }
             });

             if (isValid == false)
                          e.preventDefault();

         });


     });

<input type="text" class="input-name" id="VEHNO" name="VEHNO" type="text" />
<input type="button" value="Submit" id="someId" name="submit" />
```

Working demo is here : http://jsfiddle.net/qrj0qqrj/

Comment: Thanks you @Raghvendra Kumar

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> #submit
> ```

This is an id selector. It selects the element with the id attribute with the value *submit*.

> ```
> <input type="button" value="Submit" name="submit"/>
> ```

This element doesn't have an ID.

The `name` isn't being used for anything. Change `name` to `id`.

```
<input type="button" value="Submit" id="submit"/>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<input type="button" value="Submit" name="submit" id="submit" />
```

You can also add a return false; to the JS to stop the form submit and control it by JS.